# Duplicated querysets in each view - django

Tags: django, query-optimization

I have a few querysets that I need in each of my view. I'm wondering if there is a better way that duplicating those in every single view. Querysets results are the same for every view

They look like this

```
Company_user = Company.objects.get(User = request.user)
User_info = User_info.objects.get(User = request.user)
Groups_user = request.user.groups.values_list('name',flat = True)
Sales_company = Sales.objects.filter(Company = Company_user)
```

Comment: What do you do with this queries exactly

Comment: Mostly display informations on template (company_user.name, user_information.grade etc...). And sometimes I'm reusing those for filtering purpose like products.objects.filter(owner=company_user)

Comment: if it is for displaying info in templates, the best is using a context_processor